# How to see uploaded file details in same view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, file-upload

I uploaded a song in a view.I have to see the song details(saved file location path,file name,file size, .etc) in the same view after selecting song using 'file upload' .I tried a lot but i didn't get.Any Suggestions are accepted.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#FileUpload').change(function() {
                        var data=new FormData();
            var f = $(this)[0].files[0];

            var fDetails = 'LastModifiedDate: ' + f.lastModifiedDate + ', Name: ' + f.name + ', Size: ' + f.size + 'Bytes, Type: ' + f.type;

            alert(fDetails); // file details

                        data.append('file', f);
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'/upload',
                            type:'POST',
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            data:data,
                            success:function(resp){
                               // get other details from response
                            }
                        })
                    });
                });
            </script>


            <form action="" id="uploadFrm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Upload file from your computer<input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="file"/>
            </form>
```

you can get few Details here, other details from the response and display them in your same view. if you are using javascript,  use FileReader()